# Print a list of all available Debian source packages

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian, gnu-make

For Debian(-like) distributions, the following command prints a list of all *binary* packages available through `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
$ apt-cache search .
```

How can I obtain a similar list of all available *source* packages? I know that I can find the source package name of a binary package with:

```
$ apt-get source -s <binary-package-name> | sed -ne 's/^Fetch source //p'
```

So I certainly *could* generate the list of all available source packages with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    LANG=C
    IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(apt-cache search .); do
        apt-get source -s ${i%% *} | sed -ne 's/^Fetch source //p'
    done
) | sort -u
```

But this is really slow.

Comment: `apt-cache show $(apt-cache pkgnames) | sed -n 's/^Source: //p' | sort -u` ?

Comment: Maybe: In any case, your `$(apt-cache pkgnames)` is better than my `$(apt-cache search .)`.  But many (most?) packages are lacking a line that starts with `Source`: Maybe those where binary and source package name are identical? Can someone confirm this guess?

Comment: `apt-cache show $(apt-cache pkgnames) | awk '$1~/^Package:/{n=$2} $1~/^Source:/{n=$2} /^$/{print n}' | sort -u` ?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I had a (slower) for-loop to achieve the same. Would be my accepted (and upvoted) answer :-).